# How to do wget with cookies in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wget

I want try transfer my bash script from linux to powershell but cant understand why it failed.

Linux command:

```
wget  -q -x  --user-agent="blablabla" --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies cook.txt http://site.com/qqq
```

powershell code:

```
$source = "http://site.com/qqq"
$destination = "d:\site\qqq" 

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

but this code only download page without cookies. And i cant find how i can send PHPSESSID to site.

Please explain to me how to do it.

Comment: Is wget for windows an option?  http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget

Answer (score 13):

Ok so you have two options.

1. Run wget on Windows.
2. Set properties on the webclient object to
   replicate the functionality set by the wget flags.

The first one is easy, just download the [Windows version of wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Here is the code for the second one.

```
$source = "http://site.com/qqq"
$destination = "d:\site\qqq" 

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
# Single Example
$wc.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, "name=value")
# Multi Example
$wc.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, "name=value; name2=value2"); 
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

Look inside your cookies.txt file to get the name value pairs.

I'm not sure how to replicate the `-x` functionality of `wget`. Give the above a try and see what it does with the file after downloading.

Note - I can't test this...

Comment: Very interesting. When i use wget with cookies, webpage downloaded. But if I use powershell with cookies, i dont have result. Maybe i need send POST data to site?

Comment: @user2441498 Use fiddler to monitor capture what wget is sending to the server. Note - you may have to force wget to use a proxy.

Comment: Nice example! However, for PowerShellCore users (windows nano server), the System.Net.WebClient namespace does not seem to exsist, unfortunately.

Comment: @TormodHaugene You can probably use the PowerShell native Invoke-WebRequest rather than the .NET assembly for Core. I haven't experimented on Core though so I'm not sure what the syntax is.