# Send keystrokes to a specific window using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, download, keystroke

Is there a way to send keystrokes to a specific window using PowerShell ?
Right now I'm opening an IE window.
Then, by calling the link, a download window is opening.
I'm sending an **ALT+TAB** to switch in the download window, and **LEFT+ENTER** to confirm the download.
Is there a way to send this **LEFT+ENTER** to a specific window without having focus on it?
My code looks like that:

```
$ie=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.navigate2($url)
$ie.visible=$true
while($ie.busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
start-sleep -seconds 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{TAB}")
start-sleep -seconds 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{LEFT}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

I want to send the keystrokes to a specific window to make sure the download window gets the keystrokes even if the focus isn't on it.
I know sending keystrokes isn't the best way to download the file, but I've also tried this:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($user, $password)
$webclient.DownloadFile($urlWeb,$path)
```

I always get an 403 Error and haven't found a solution yet to solve this problem...

Comment: Recommend switching to Firefox and employing the iMacros add-on for automation within that browser.

Comment: Regrading 403 error: maybe you have to send cookies with request. Use Fiddler/Debug tools to view cookies and see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16864171/4424236) to use them with WebClient.

Comment: @nimizen using firefox is no opinion, because the script has to run on diffenrent systems and not all of them have firefox installed...

Comment: @beatcracker I already saw the question you linked and tried the suggested solution but had no success with that...

Comment: @npit Is that a public site, where anyone can register and download file? Can we have a test link?

Comment: @beatcracker sadly it isn't a public site. But I found this [link](http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip) that has nearly the same behavior. the only different is that in my case it is a .csv file instead of .zip
Behavior= open the link and child window opens with an dialog to choose save or open and so on.

Comment: I haven't personally used it, but it sounds like WASP (Windows Automation Snapin for Powershell) might be a good solution for you.  https://wasp.codeplex.com/  It allows Powershell to control Windows applications like a user is performing the actions.

Comment: If you really want to send keystrokes to a Window without focus, one technique is using Win32 APIs like PostMessage to send a series of WM_CHAR messages or similar. Probably a lot simpler is to use the BITS service, which has PS cmdlets (eg Add-BitsFile). Or even  [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) for Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really a fan of SendKeys cause it almost always fail. If I use the provided link, I'm able to download the file with this Powershell code:

```
$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
$target = "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"
$folder = "C:\TEMP\5MB.zip"

$web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$web.Headers.Add("user-agent", $userAgent)
$web.DownloadFile($target, $folder)
```

You might also need to add network credentials.